# Langlands program and complexity theory

Tags: computational-complexity, modular-forms, computational-number-theory, langlands-conjectures, conjectures

Back when I was an undergraduate, I spent some time reading the about the modularity conjecture, but the details are fuzzy now.

One of the motivations I **imagined**  for the Langlands program was for generating algorithms for difficult discrete computational problems (e.g., NP-hard) in complexity theory. The solution was to go something like this:

1. Take your discrete problem (e.g., 3-SAT) and convert it to a Diophantine equation with certain properties.
2. Using the correct generalization of the Modularity Conjecture, find the "analytic object" associated with that Diophantine equation.
3. Use the analytic properties of the "analytic object" to find the solution to the discrete problem, perhaps by computing something about the "analytic object" and going backwards.

Is this all nonsense? If it isn't nonsense, is it too hopeful? Are there more realistic (but maybe still overly "wishful") connections between the Langlands program and complexity theory?

EDIT: We do not even need to consider traditional discrete CS problems. From [this paper](http://sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000078900442), we have that solvability of $aX^2+bY−c=0$ in non-negative integers is NP-complete. Should I hope that Modern Number Theory may lead to more efficient ways to solve this equation?

Comment: The problem with this plan is that the Diophantine equations generated from discrete computational problems are usually a mess, i.e., very complicated with no clear arithmetic structure. Modern number theory doesn't really have anything to say about such equations.

Comment: Going from problems like 3-SAT to Diophantine equations is pretty easy, but solving them is very hard, even if you assume very strong conjectures like Langlands. You are probably familiar with Hilbert's 10th problem, whose resolution says that in general it is not algorithmically possible, let alone feasible, to solve general Diophantine equations. Langlands only does, and only can, help solve equations which are particularly "nice".

Comment: It’s $ax^2+by-c=0$, not $ax^2+by^2-c=0$. I suppose the latter is reducible to factoring, hence (likely) not NP-complete. (Actually, one may even take $a=1$, i.e., $x^2+by-c=0$ is still NP-complete.) And importantly, these NP-completeness results are for *nonnegative* integer solutions; solvability of $ax^2+by-c=0$ in integers is again reducible to factoring (or rather, square residuosity).

Comment: yes, thank you, that was just a typo.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Today I learnt a new word.

Comment: @Wojowu Can you please explain what did you mean by "nice" diophantine equations?

Comment: @roydiptajit I don't know of any specific sort of definition I could point you to. The general point is, to any diophantine equation you can attach a variety or a scheme, but most of them will have nothing to do with Shimura varieties or whatever objects you encounter in Langlands theory.